# Add watermark to image with imagick PHP

Tags: php, imagick, php-extension

I'm adding `watermark.png` to `original.png`, but I have 3 problems:

1. I want to set `watermatk.png` on the bottom right
2. I want to resize `watermark.png` and make it smaller or bigger
3. Is there any way to make watermark transparent if background was white?

---

```
<?php
// Open the original image
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage("./man/original.png");

// Open the watermark
$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage("./man/watermark.png");

// Overlay the watermark on the original image
$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);

// send the result to the browser
header("Content-Type: image/" . $image->getImageFormat());
echo $image;
```

Comment: Background should be transparent, not white, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a "watermark" command which will handle your opacity issue. Combine it with gravity + geometry to get the size and position that you want.

```
composite -watermark 30% -gravity north -geometry 150x150+100+50 watermark.png input.jpg output.png
```

Something like that. I have not tried this, but hopefully it gets you on your way. Let us know how it works out.